# Target css group of class or id?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a group of class name:

```
.hSpace5{padding-top:0.3125em;}
.hSpace10{padding-top:0.625em;}
.hSpace15{padding-top:0.9375em;}
.hSpace20{padding-top:1.25em;}
.hSpace25{padding-top:1.5625em;}
.hSpace30{padding-top:1.875em;}
.hSpace35{padding-top:2.1875em;}
.hSpace40{padding-top:2.5em;}
```

Is it possible to target all this class names by referring to the to the first few characters .hSapce--?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below selector to select all elements whose class attribute contains the value *hspace*. Note that this is a contains selector and hence the string can be present anywhere in the class name.

```
div[class*='hspace'] {
   /* styles */ 
}
```

```css
div[class*='hspace'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='hspace1'>aa</div>
<div class='hspace2'>bb</div>
<div class='hspace-b'>ab</div>
<div class='c-hspace'>cd</div>
<div class='hvspace'>cd</div>
<!-- will not be selected -->
```

But check out for browser support.

---

As mentioned in Rab Nawaz's answer, you can use the below also.

```
div[class^='hspace'] { }
```

In-fact, this method might be more suitable for your case because it selects all `div` whose `class` starts with `hspace`.

More information can be found in this [W3C Selectors Level 3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) in the table present under Section 2.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it like this  in css3

```
div[class^="hSpace"]
```

OR

```
div[class*="hSpace"]
```

Both are not similar but in your scenario both will work.

First is "starts with class name" and second is "contains class name".

Comment: Are these actually CSS3 selectors? They work in legacy browsers (IE7+)

Comment: Are they both similar? if not please explain it or just provide a link.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Both are not similar mate. First is "starts with" and second is "contains".

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: Yes, they were introduced in CSS3. I think CSS 2 only had `=`, `~=` and `|=` (although I think they performed similar functions).

Comment: @Harry I know.. I was actually meant to say that the post is missing explanation.. :)